# Sencha CMD: 404 errors when running built production version

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-cmd

I have converted my existing ExtJS 4.1.3 application to use the Sencha CMD recommended structure and tools. I created the structure first, then put my existing app JS files at the place where the single-page JS app should be located.

I currently access the development version of my application at:

```
{my-server-side-app-url}/sws/dt/index.jsp
```

where `sws` is the [Sencha workspace](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_workspace) and `dt` is the [Sencha single-page app](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_app_single). So far, no problems I believe. Then I run the command:

```
sencha app build
```

within my `app`'s directory. This completes with several `Yui Compressor Warning (Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initializer` warnings, but no errors. So I the *production* `index.jsp` page (which uses `all-classes.js` file, which receives the concatenated output of the `app build` command above) at URL:

```
{my-server-side-app-url}/sws/build/dt/production/index.jsp
```

The issue occurs when `all-classes.js` attempts to load several files which *in theory should be included within itself*. These include the controllers which are specified in *app.js*.

Why are these files not being concatenated in `all-classes.js`? Below is a screenshot of Chrome attempting to load them from `all-classes.js`, and of course not finding them.

[image]

*What did I try?*
Tried to tweak my `app.js` to *require* the controllers via [`requires`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires); or to make the classes required available via [`uses`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-uses) as recommended by this [question/answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457508/using-sencha-cmd-with-dynamically-loaded-controllers), but to no avail.

Comment: something strange... I am using the same structure, I've used `sencha generate app` to generate my app, and it works for me... In your case only your custom classes don't load?

Comment: @bhovhannes There are some controllers and some custom classes, in addition to files named `belongsto.js` and `hasmany.js` which are referred to by my own model classes; indeed only these model classes `App` and `Window` are not loading. Will try to *play* with them, but really can't understand why I see no prob with dev, and at production it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include all classes you need inside [`uses`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-uses) or [`requires`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires) section of your `app.js`.

Note, that if controller is requiring some views, you may omit that view in require section of `app.js`, since it will be included anyway when sencha tool will be parsing your controller.

Try to use full paths when adding files to `uses`/`requires` section of `app.js`. That is, write `MyApp.controller.pages.Home` or `MyApp.store.users.List` but now `pages.Home` or `users.List`.

You can use `-before-build` and `-after-build` Ant targets to modify your app.js just before sencha tool's YUI minimizer phase start.
In my case I ended up with searching for all controllers inside `app/controller` folder and adding their names to `uses` section of `app.js`. For it that was enough, since other needed classes were required from within my controllers.

In order to be able to find uses section of app.js, I've used special comment

```
/*ant-generated-content-start*/ /*ant-generated-content-end*/
```

My `app.js`

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    appFolder: 'app',

    controllers: [
        "main.App"
    ],

    uses: [
        /*ant-generated-content-start*/ /*ant-generated-content-end*/
    ],
    autoCreateViewport: true,
});
```

My `build.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="MyApp" default=".help">
    <import file="${basedir}/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml"/>

    <target name="-before-build">

        <echo message="Collecting all controllers in application class property ... "/>
        <fileset id="app_controllers" dir="${app.dir}/app/controller" casesensitive="yes">
            <include name="**/*.js"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathconvert pathsep="," property="app_controller_names" refid="app_controllers" targetos="unix">
            <chainedmapper>
                <globmapper from="${app.dir}/app/*" to="${ant.project.name}/*" casesensitive="no" handledirsep="yes"/>
                <chainedmapper>
                    <regexpmapper from="^(.*)\.js$$" to='"\1"'/>
                    <filtermapper>
                        <replacestring from="/" to="."/>
                        <replacestring from="\" to="."/>
                    </filtermapper>
                </chainedmapper>
            </chainedmapper>
        </pathconvert>
        <echo message="Collected controllers: ${app_controller_names}"/>

        <echo message="Injecting into app.js ..."/>
        <replaceregexp file="${app.dir}/app/app.js"
                       match="/\*ant-generated-content-start\*/(.*)/\*ant-generated-content-end\*/"
                       replace="/*ant-generated-content-start*/ ${app_controller_names} /*ant-generated-content-end*/"
                       byline="true"
                />
    </target>

    <target name="-after-build">
        <echo message="Reverting to original app.js ..."/>
        <replaceregexp file="${app.dir}/app/app.js"
                       match="/\*ant-generated-content-start\*/(.*)/\*ant-generated-content-end\*/"
                       replace="/*ant-generated-content-start*/ /*ant-generated-content-end*/"
                       byline="true"
                />
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand the problem fully but this is what I did to fix the issue.

I had two models; `App.js` and `Window.js` which had a `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relationship respectively. In `App.js`:

```
associations: [{
    type : 'hasMany',
    model: 'WD.model.Window',
    name : 'windows'
}]
```

while in `Window.js` I had:

```
associations: [{
    type : 'belongsTo',
    model: 'WD.model.App',
    associationKey: 'appId'
}]
```

I started to suspect these parts as causing the problem because they were the only ExtJS modules giving a `404`; the other modules that give a `404` depend on the model files which use `hasMany` and `belongsTo`.

I simply removed the `associations` snippets pasted above (because right now I'm not using them as they don't really work, because I still have to load the data myself rather than children being loaded automagically). Then re-ran `sencha app build`, and the production version **works** properly!

If anyone (**particularly someone from Sencha**) knows exactly why my clumsy fix works, please answer the question or comment below, and I will update the answer.

Thanks [@bhovhannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898580/bhovhannes) for your answer which still led to useful insight to the problem; +1ed.

Comment: did you tried to add `Ext.require('WD.model.Window')` at the top of `App.js` and `Ext.require('WD.model.App')` at the top of `Window.js`? maybe sencha tool doesn't goes through `associations` ...

Comment: @bhovhannes Yep I did; didn't work, and if it worked, it would have been ugly.. as it simply should go through them.

Answer (score 0):

I had equal problem too,, 
To solve this problem I just change the name of class. I built using SenchaCmd 3.1.xx and Sencha Touch 2.2